# Magento Data MIgration Tool for 1.9.2.2 to 2 - Mismatch of entities in the document

Tags: magento2, migration, entities, data

I'm trying to upgrade to Magento 2, but hit another roadblock. I'm currently getting an error of

> [ERROR]: Mismatch of entities in the document: eav_attribute_group

What is my next step for troubleshooting?

I have very little experience with Magento, please give me the dumbed down version if possible.

Thanks!

I also do have this map file, if it matters.

```
<group name="ignore">
    <attribute>msrp_enabled</attribute>
    <attribute>group_price</attribute>
    <attribute>umm_cat_label</attribute>
    <attribute>umm_dd_type</attribute>
    <attribute>umm_dd_proportions</attribute>
    <attribute>umm_dd_columns</attribute>
    <attribute>umm_dd_blocks</attribute>
</group>
```

Comment: Rohit, I'm not quite sure you felt the need to edit my English to change from I'm to I am. There are many questions on StackExchange where people use I'm... and it is correct usage of the English language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run `select * from eav_attribute_group;` and `select * from eav_attribute_set;` on both your source and destination databases after the failure, and you can see what the differences are in the tables.

I ended up echoing out the validation checks at the bottom of `src/Migration/Step/Eav/Volume.php` instead of adding them to the `$this->errors[]` array.

The data in those two tables still looked fine in my case, so I think this is fairly safe. YMMV.

In addition, I later ran into a strange issue where during the migration the code was using `SHOW TABLES` to ensure if a table existed, and if it didn't, it would error out. Turns out the table did exist, but it was running into a memory limit issue. I changed the `const MAX_BULK_SIZE` in `src/Migration/ResourceModel/AbstractResource.php` from 50000 to 5000, which solved that issue as well.